# How to import multiple .csv files, from multiple folders and skip rows, at once?

Tags: r

Suppose I have three folders in my working directory. Each contains another folder (annoying, I know) that is named according to the day of the week data was collected. Within each of these folders, are .csv files on an individual, all in the same format, containing data for analysis. I wish to read in each folder within the directory as a data.frame, binding rows for days of the week and by each individual.

For example, read in 06052018/Monday/PersonA.csv then 06052018/Monday/PersonB.csv then 06052018/Tuesday/PersonA.csv and create two new columns within this `data.frame` that contain information on each file's corresponding day of week and person.

I know that I can read in multiple .csv files and create a new column for file name using:

```
library(tidyverse)

read_plus <- function(flnm) {
  read_csv(flnm) %>% 
    mutate(filename = flnm)
}

tbl_with_sources <-
  list.files(pattern = "*.csv", 
             full.names = F) %>% 
  map_df(~read_plus(.))
```

How do I extend this, for multiple folders and files within folders, within folders?

Thank you.

Comment: In the `list.files`, there is `include.dirs` and `recursive` options (both are `FALSE` by default) or use `dir`

Comment: Ah, I feel very silly now. I accept your comment as an answer and close the question!